# POS Tagger for declension of german words in Java

Tags: java, nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

The [RFTagger](https://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eschmid/tools/RFTagger/) is a Part-Of-Speech Tagger with very detailed tags for german words.

According to their website, output looks like this:

| word | part of speech |
| --- | --- |
| Das | `PRO.Dem.Subst.-3.Nom.Sg.Neut` |
| ist | `VFIN.Sein.3.Sg.Pres.Ind` |
| ein | `ART.Indef.Nom.Sg.Masc` |
| Test | `N.Reg.Nom.Sg.Masc` |
| . | `SYM.Pun.Sent` |

**The tags contain information about the respective word's declension. This information is what I need.**
However the [RFTagger](https://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eschmid/tools/RFTagger/) is pretty outdated (available [here](http://sifnos.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/resource/A4/rftj/) as Beta for Java 6).

Is there any alternative POSTagger out there that is able to give me the declension of a german word?

Comment: What do you mean by 'outdated'? German morphology isn't changing that quickly.

Comment: @OliverMason Correct. The morphology isn't outdated, but the RFTagger itself is. I tested it and it does not work with Java 8 or above as it was written in Java 6. (the dependency com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Comment: You can download the source code from that page, apparently with Linux binaries (not sure if they would still work); if all fails, just ask the author...

Comment: @OliverMason Correct, there is a download link. However the downloadable version is in Beta and only for Java 6. Asking the author is an interesting option, but I wanted to look out for available, Java 8+ compatible POS Taggers with RFTagger's capability first.